# JS. Как получить сумму столбцов массивов?

Tags: javascript

Есть:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0]
[1, 2, 3,]
[1, 2]
```

Нужен результат в виде одного массива, где индексы будут суммой столбцов, т.е.

```
[3, 6, 6, 0]
```

**UPDATED:**
Ответ:

```
var array = [
        [1, 2, 3, 0],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2]
    ],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (b, i) {
            r[i] = (r[i] || 0) + b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);
```

p.s. @Олег Дёгтев пнул в нужном направлении =)

Comment: Мой ответ абсолютно не верен, вам необходимо воспользоваться другим решением, напрмер @Qwertiy

Comment: Все норм, главное задать направление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:** Ответ не верный, посчитал цифры не в том направлении.

```
console.log(
      [
          [1, 2, 3, 0].reduce( function(sum, i) {return sum + i} ),
          [1, 2, 3,].reduce( function(sum, i) {return sum + i} ),
          [1, 2].reduce( function(sum, i) {return sum + i} )
      ]
  );
```

`.reduce()` проходит по каждому элементу массива `i` и сохраняет промежуточный результат в `sum`.

**UPD2:** Раз уж так и висит галка напротив моего ответа, добавлю еще одну возможную реализацию, считающую сумму в правильном "направлении", основанную на других ответах

```
console.log(
  [
    [1, 2, 3, 0],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2]
  ].reduce(function (sum, arr) {
    arr.map(function(val, i) {
      sum[i] = val + (sum[i] || 0);
    });

    return sum;  
  });
);
```

Comment: странно почему ответ помечен как верный, если результат не соответствует ожидаемому в вопросе

Comment: Ваc не смущает, что этот код возвращает [6, 6, 3] вместо требуемых [3, 6, 6, 0]? :)

Comment: Автор странный, просил одно, а принял ответ, который делает совсем другое.

Comment: `Нужен результат в виде одного массива, где индексы будут суммой столбцов`. Ответил на этот вопрос, а дальше какая-то "магия"

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, собственно вы просуммировали строки

Comment: @Grundy: Я предположил, что автору именно это и нужно в его актуальной задаче, которую он пытается решить прямо сейчас. Я не заставлял его принимать именно мой ответ. Если лично вас ответ не устроил, просто поставьте минус и ступайте дальше, для меня же важно что я попытался помочь и, видимо, помог.

Comment: @Grundy: Я в корне не прав. Не так понял задачу. Приношу свои извинения.

Comment: Пошел в правильном направлении, вот и бырал

Comment: @ОлегДёгтев, вместо `map` в данном случае лучше `forEach` - он не возвращает новый массив

Answer (score 3):

Например, как-то так:

```
"use strict"
let arr = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]];
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let subarr = arr[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < subarr.length; j++) {
        if (result[j] == undefined)
            result[j] = 0;
        result[j] += subarr[j];
    }
}
console.log(result); // [3, 6, 6, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант с [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), на основе [ответа @Yaant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508095/186999)

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]];

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc,cur){
    return cur.reduce(function(innerAcc, innerCur,index){
        innerAcc[index]=(innerAcc[index]||0)+innerCur; 
        return innerAcc;
    },acc);
},[]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[
[1, 2, 3, 0],
[1, 2, 3],
[1, 2]
].reduce(function (res, cur) { 
  for (var q=0; q<cur.length; ++q) {
    if (!res[q]) res[q] = 0;
    res[q] += cur[q];
  }

  return res;
}, [])
```

Comment: опередил чутка :-)

Answer (score 1):

Можно без этих ваших `reduce()`, по-простому:

```js
function columnSum(arr) {
  var i, j, out = arr[0].slice();
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      out[j] = (j < out.length ? out[j] : 0) + arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

document.body.innerText = columnSum([
  [1, 2, 3, 0],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2]
]).join(', ');
```

Вариант (наверное?) быстрее, чем у @Yaant тем, что первая строка сразу копируется в выход, а не по одному элементу.

Comment: ага, это как раз вариант Yaant'a :-) единственное - `if` на тернарный оператор заменен.

Comment: а, у меня на массив меньше! : )

Comment: ага, это если можно менять содержимое :-)

Comment: Вы правы, изменять входной не есть гут. Обновил ответ. Мой вариант (наверное?) быстрее, чем у @Yaant тем, что первая строка сразу копируется в выход, а не по одному элементу.

Comment: можно на jsperf проверить, но мне что-то лень :)

Comment: Неожиданно, метод Yaant [быстрее раза в 4](http://jsperf.com/array-slice-vs-for).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37713/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergiks).